# How do I loop through a list of existing ip's in a list and fill in whats not there?

Tags: python, django, algorithm, loops, oracle11g

*UPDATED

So I tried using your query there is just one problem with it I honestly dont quite understand all the joins your doing my oracle skills are not that good. I changed it to suit what I was doing but it will always stop on the last known ip and not continue until 256.

('100.10.16.14', '', '', None)
('100.10.32.1', 'Not assigned', 'Not assigned', '172.16.32.25')

also that actually needs to be the customer name and vm_name from the vm_ip_address_histories table. Thank you for you help but if you could explain your query a little more so I could change it to meet my needs that would be awesome.

Let me give a more detailed example. We have two tables ip_addresses which is a table that holds all ip addresses that can be assigned, and a vm_ip_address_histories when an ip is assigned it gets a ip_address_id which is foreign key to ip_addresses, then onces its DE-assigned it gets a deallocation date. I am trying to find all current ips that dont have a deallocation date which i was already doing. Then im trying to fill in the games with the Not Assigned. Currently I modified your query to select the ips from the table but it stops at the last known ip and doesn't continue to 256, also I'm not entirely sure how to get it to acutally insert the customers name and vm_name from the vm_ip_address_histories table which just has a vm_id linked to the vms tables.

Here is what I changed it to:

```
with ips_from_db$ as (
                select raw2ip(a.ip_address) as ip
                from ip_addresses a, vm_ip_address_histories b where a.ip_address_id = b.ip_address_id and deallocation_date is null
            ),
            stripped_to_levels$ as (
                select ip,
                    regexp_substr(ip, '^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.', 1, 1, null, 1) as level_123,
                    to_number(regexp_substr(ip, '\.(\d+)$', 1, 1, null, 1)) as level_4
                from ips_from_db$
            ),
            max_level_4$ as (
                select level_123, max(level_4) as max_level_4, min(level_4) as min_level_4
                from stripped_to_levels$
                group by level_123
            ),
            all_level_4_values$ as (
                select level as new_level_4
                from dual
                connect by level <= 255
            )
            select ML.level_123||'.'||AL.new_level_4 as ip,
                case when SL.ip is null then 'Not assigned' else '<your customer name>' end as customer_name,
                case when SL.ip is null then 'Not assigned' else '<your vm name>' end as vm_name,
                case when lag(1) over (partition by ML.level_123 order by AL.new_level_4) is null then ML.level_123||'.'||ML.min_level_4 end as break_info
            from max_level_4$ ML
                join all_level_4_values$ AL
                    on AL.new_level_4 <= ML.max_level_4
                left join stripped_to_levels$ SL
                    on SL.level_123 = ML.level_123
                    and SL.level_4 = AL.new_level_4
            order by ML.level_123, AL.new_level_4
```

I have a script that pulls IP information from a database. I then take that returned information save it into a list and order it. Then I loop through the information by IP.

Its logic looks for a change in the IP's first three positions 100.100.100 and ignores the last .100. Once and of the three positions change, it will insert a break into the list and start again. I'm doing this because it is in conjunction with Django and I had to find a way to separate the div tags by IP.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to fill in the missing IP Addresses, I haven't written any code because I can't think of an algorithm that would do it.

I'm looking more for ideas on how I could do what it is I want to do. I basically want it to fill in the IP address between entries with the IP address that should be there.

**for example if there are the following IP's assigned to a customer**

```
100.100.101.1
100.100.101.3
100.100.102.5
100.100.102.10
```

the following list would output

```
          NewIP 100.100.101.1 First
100.100.101.1   customer name     vmname
100.100.101.2   Not assigned     Not assigned
100.100.101.3  customer name     vmname
          NewIP 100.100.102.5 Break
100.100.102.0 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.1 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.2 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.3 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.4 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.5  customer name     vmname
100.100.102.6 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.7 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.8 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.9 Not assigned       Not assigned
100.100.102.10  customer name     vmname
```

**Current Code:**

```
sql = ''' select
               customer_name,
               vm_name,
               raw2ip(ip_address)
               from
               customers a,
               vm_groups b,
               vms c,
               vm_ip_address_histories d,
               ip_addresses e
               where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
               and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
               and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
               and d.deallocation_date is null
               and e.ip_address_id = d.ip_address_id
               order by 3
               '''
cursor.execute(sql)
first = True
ip_list = []
for customer_name, vm_name, ip in cursor:
         #first time throught
   ip_list.append((customer_name, vm_name, ip))

ip_list = sorted(ip_list, key=itemgetter(2))     
ip_new_list = []  

for customer_name, vm_name, ip in ip_list:    
            if first:
               ip_check = str(ip).split('.')[0] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[1] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[2]
               ip_x = str(ip).split('.')[3]
               ip_new_list.append(('Newip', ip, 'First'))
               ip_new_list.append((ip,vm_name,customer_name))
               first = False
            else:
                  if ip_check in ip:
                     ip_new_list.append((ip,vm_name,customer_name))
                  else:
                     ip_new_list.append(('Newip', ip,'Break'))
                     ip_check = str(ip).split('.')[0] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[1] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[2]
                     ip_new_list.append((ip,vm_name,customer_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Oracle SQL solution to your problem might be as follows ...

(Don't be scared of the length of the query. It's just heavily layered, not complicated.)

```
with ips_from_db$ as (
    select column_value as ip
    from table(sys.ora_mining_varchar2_nt('100.100.101.1','100.100.101.3','100.100.102.5','100.100.102.10')) X
),
stripped_to_levels$ as (
    select ip,
        regexp_substr(ip, '^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.', 1, 1, null, 1) as level_123,
        to_number(regexp_substr(ip, '\.(\d+)$', 1, 1, null, 1)) as level_4
    from ips_from_db$
),
max_level_4$ as (
    select level_123, max(level_4) as max_level_4, min(level_4) as min_level_4
    from stripped_to_levels$
    group by level_123
),
all_level_4_values$ as (
    select level as new_level_4
    from dual
    connect by level <= 255
)
select ML.level_123||'.'||AL.new_level_4 as ip,
    case when SL.ip is null then 'Not assigned' else '<your customer name>' end as customer_name,
    case when SL.ip is null then 'Not assigned' else '<your vm name>' end as vm_name,
    case when lag(1) over (partition by ML.level_123 order by AL.new_level_4) is null then ML.level_123||'.'||ML.min_level_4 end as break_info
from max_level_4$ ML
    join all_level_4_values$ AL
        on AL.new_level_4 <= ML.max_level_4
    left join stripped_to_levels$ SL
        on SL.level_123 = ML.level_123
        and SL.level_4 = AL.new_level_4
order by ML.level_123, AL.new_level_4
;
```

The output of the query (run on 11gR2) is:

```
IP               CUSTOMER_NAME        VM_NAME        BREAK_INFO
---------------- -------------------- -------------- ----------------
100.100.101.1    <your customer name> <your vm name> 100.100.101.1
100.100.101.2    Not assigned         Not assigned   
100.100.101.3    <your customer name> <your vm name> 
100.100.102.1    Not assigned         Not assigned   100.100.102.5
100.100.102.2    Not assigned         Not assigned   
100.100.102.3    Not assigned         Not assigned   
100.100.102.4    Not assigned         Not assigned   
100.100.102.5    <your customer name> <your vm name> 
100.100.102.6    Not assigned         Not assigned   
100.100.102.7    Not assigned         Not assigned   
100.100.102.8    Not assigned         Not assigned   
100.100.102.9    Not assigned         Not assigned   
100.100.102.10   <your customer name> <your vm name>
```

Comment: However, comparing this to your example result, this solution is missing the `100.100.102.0` row. Please explain your need (if there's any) for this particular row and why there's no `100.100.101.0` row as well.

Comment: basically we have a table of assigned ips to our current infrastructures active VM's that is updated every 6 minutes, I'm trying to create a dynamic django web page. so as far as your query could I just have python insert those values because there just arent that few of them there are roughly 450 assigned ip's and 12 subnets.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. :-)

Comment: its ok, I just wanted to list from 0 on to 256. I figured it out with pure python. I need to get better at SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I ended up doing it, its not the most efficient, but I'm sure as my product grows im going to expand on it:

```
   cursor = oracle.cursor()  
   sql = ''' select
                  customer_name,
                  vm_name,
                  raw2ip(ip_address)
                  from
                  customers a,
                  vm_groups b,
                  vms c,
                  vm_ip_address_histories d,
                  ip_addresses e
                  where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
                  and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id
                  and c.vm_id = d.vm_id
                  and d.deallocation_date is null
                  and e.ip_address_id = d.ip_address_id
                  order by 3
                  '''
   cursor.execute(sql)
   first = True
   ip_list = []

   for customer_name, vm_name, ip in cursor:
      ip_list.append((customer_name, vm_name, ip))
      ip_list = sorted(ip_list, key=itemgetter(2))     
      ip_new_list = []      
      for customer_name, vm_name, ip in ip_list:    
            if first:
               ip_check = str(ip).split('.')[0] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[1] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[2]
               ip_new_list.append((ip_check))
               first = False
            else:
                  if ip_check in ip:
                     pass
                  else:
                     ip_check = str(ip).split('.')[0] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[1] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[2]
                     ip_new_list.append((ip_check))  

   ip_list_build = []
   for ip in ip_new_list:
      for lastdigit in range(0,256):
         ip_list_build.append((str(ip) + "." + str(lastdigit)))


   for customer, vm, ip in ip_list:
      index = ip_list_build.index(ip)
      ip_list_build[index] = (customer,vm, ip)

   for line in ip_list_build:
      if len(line) == 3:
         continue
      else:
         index = ip_list_build.index(line)
         ip_list_build[index] = ('None', 'None', line)   

   ip_new_list = []      
   for customer_name, vm_name, ip in ip_list_build:    
            if first:
               ip_check = str(ip).split('.')[0] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[1] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[2]
               ip_new_list.append(('Newip', ip, 'First'))
               ip_new_list.append((ip,vm_name,customer_name))
               first = False
            else:
                  if ip_check in ip:
                     ip_new_list.append((ip,vm_name,customer_name))
                  else:
                     ip_new_list.append(('Newip', ip,'Break'))
                     ip_check = str(ip).split('.')[0] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[1] + "." + str(ip).split('.')[2]
                     ip_new_list.append((ip,vm_name,customer_name))
```